# Marcador con tiempo android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-sites, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Buenas noches estoy realizando un mapa, pero  me gustaria saber si se puede hacer para que un marcador se visualize por un tiempo determinado alguna ayuda o guía por favor

Answer (score 0):

Para que un marcador se deje de visualizar luego de un tiempo tienes el timer o el handler para realizar una acción luego de un tiempo.

Esto codigo esta en kotlin:

```
    val tiempo = 1000 * 60  //1 min en milisengundos
    Timer().schedule(object: TimerTask(){
        override fun run() {
  
          //quitar marcador
        }

    },tiempo)


    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({

        //quitar marcador
    },tiempo)
```